# How to use column header as the x-axis in ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, date-and-time, csv-format, head, headers-footers

I imported a csv file, and the header of the columns are specific dates. How would I plot these points using ListPlot, but the x-axis instead of 1,2,3, etc, is the dates from the column headers?
For example, the Header says 1/1/2020, 1/2/2020, and so on. How to make those the x-axis.

Comment: consider  using [DateListPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html) instead of `ListPlot`?

Answer (score 1):

You may use DateListPlot. Toward this aim do the following:
Assume your data has the following form:

```
dat = {{"1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020"}, {10, 20}, {15, 25}, {35, 
    45}};
```

You must first change the dates into DateObjects.
Then you must assemble the individual time series.
Finally you can plot them with DateListPlot:

```
dat = {{"1/1/2020", "2/1/2020", "3/1/2020"}, {10, 20}, {15, 25}, {35, 
    45}};
labels = DateObject /@ dat[[1]];
timeseries = Transpose[{labels, #}] & /@ Transpose[Rest[dat]]
DateListPlot[timeseries]
```